# Why would Tony Stark need to drink Chlorophyll?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2

In *Iron Man 2*, Tony Stark is suffering from Palladium poisoning due to having to use the element Palladium as the core for his ARC reactor.  In order to combat the effects this has on his body he drinks liquid [Chlorophyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll).  It is my understanding that Chlorophyll's main function is photosynthesis, so why would this somehow aid in alleviating blood poisoning from a rare metal?

Comment: This is off-topic. No questions regarding scientific explanations!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath But the question isn't asking specifically for a scientific explanation. It's just asking for an explanation. And there is no rule against scientific explanations in answers.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

According to [Health Benefits of Liquid Chlorophyll](http://www.energiseforlife.com/wordpress/2009/02/11/health-benefits-of-liquid-chlorophyll/), one of its supposed benefits is:

> **Chelation of Heavy Metals:** chlorophyll is one of the most important chelates in nature. It’s ability to bind to and remove toxic heavy metals such as mercury makes it an extremely powerful healer. I’m about to have four mercury fillings removed, and you can bet that I will be getting PLENTY of chlorophyll into my body after the procedure!

Whether there are actual studies to back this up might be a good question for [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), but this at least explains why a fictional character suffering from heavy metal poisoning might be taking liquid chlorophyll.

Comment: Chlorophyll binds a magnesium ion in nature, so it is possible that it can bind other divalent ions as well. But you would have to either remove the Mg or the Palladium would need to bind much tighter for it to work. In practice one would use much simpler #(but less cool) chelators for heavy metal poisoning like EDTA or similar compounds to treat heavy metal poisoning.

Answer (score 10):

[Chlorophyll](http://www.livestrong.com/article/489526-what-are-the-benefits-of-drinking-liquid-chlorophyll/) is an antioxidant, among other things:

> The liquid form of chlorophyll is a **health supplement** that some claim will provide you with many of the benefits of eating vegetables and fruits that contain chlorophyll.
>
> Liquid chlorophyll can **increase the quality and quantity of your red blood cells** because the compound has a chemical composition very similar to hemoglobin.
>
> The antioxidant properties also can **reduce inflammation in your body**. This action can benefit from medical disorders characterized by increased inflammation such as arthritis and amygdalitis. Your **immune system also can benefit** from antioxidation, since your immune cells function better in the absence of free radicals.